# Can't get text out of quote area in summernote editor

Tags: summernote

I'm having trouble getting out of quote mode when in the editor.

I'm trying to put the "Can't get out of quote mode below it" out of the quote section and choosing normal in the format dropdown doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: oops - context of issue didn't make sense without the image.  Will try to upload it and provide the link,

Comment: http://www.maplewoodonline.com/forum_update/quote_issue.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known bug:
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/42